# GTM Tag Template API - callback

Tags: templates, google-tag-manager

I am trying to load a function from cdn, using GTM API template functions.
the injection of the js function works fine and I can see the library load, but the callback function which is something I am not able to implement.

```
const injectScript = require('injectScript');
const logToConsole = require('logToConsole');
const addEventCallback = require('addEventCallback');

data.gtmOnSuccess();
data.gtmOnFailure();

addEventCallback(function(id){
          logToConsole.log("template id "+id);
     });

const url = "js function loading via js that returns an id if called";
injectScript(url, data.gtmOnSuccess, data.gtmOnFailure, 'token');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to define the callback function before the tag was fired in html. And that worked.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).